# What is the name of this green berry tree?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Location: South India

Month: May

Location: Outside, Metropolitan.

Tree with berry fruits (poisonous or not, I don't know):

[image]

Its leaves:

[image]

Comment: @JM97 "Before I die, I will definitely find one or more new unknown species." from the profile - maybe hoping that one day they can post a plant no one can identify?

Comment: Leaves and branches apparently looking like [Carissa carandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carissa_carandas); but no comments about edibility of OP's specimen.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I am afraid, It is not [Carissa carandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carissa_carandas), leaf design not matching with my plant.

Comment: Don't taste unknown fruits. However no idea about leaf size from the post.